# Why continue to omit the Ten Commandments in Jewish liturgy?

Tags: aseres-hadibros

The Ten Commandments were included in the Temple service, then were removed.  The Talmud says:

> Rav Yehudah said in the name of Shmuel: [The Sages] wished to recite [the Ten Commandments with the Shema] ... but soon abolished them because of the arguments of the minim [heretics], [that the Ten Commandments were the only valid part of the Torah.] ... [Later still,] Rabbah bar bar Chanah sought to reinstitute [the recitation of the Ten Commandments] in Sura [a great academy in Babylon], but Rav Chisda said to him:  They already abolished their recitation because of the arguments of the minim. [Even later,] Amemar sought to reinstitute [the recitation of the Ten Commandments] in Nehardea, but Rav Ashi said to him, They already abolished their recitation because of the arguments of the minim. [Berachot 12a; also in Mishna 5:1 in Tamid 32b]

So the Ten Commandments were left out of the service for fear that the average passer-by (who, as we know, always has the IQ of a cauliflower) would hear them and conclude that they are the only commandments Jews need to observe.

Now that our IQ has risen, do we still need to keep the Ten Commandments out of the liturgy?  Should we bring them back?  If a congregation did, would they be violating halacha?

**Added note**:  We are talking ONLY about inclusion in services.  There are many opinions that reciting them after services is OK.  (But "after" and "during" are exercises in semantics.)  -The Baal Ha-Turim (14th-century Spain): People should say them privately. -Rabbi Joseph Karo (16th-century Israel, Shulchan Arukh): The ban only applies to public recitation during service.  They may be said privately after the service. They are included for that purpose in most prayerbooks.  -Rabbi Moshe Isserles (16th-century Poland): One may recite them any time, but not in public. -Jews in Fostat, near Cairo, Egypt, in 10th-12th centuries, read the Ten Commandments after services.

Comment: Who said our IQ has risen? I've met many cauliflowers

Comment: It wasn't that the passersby weren't bright. It was that they denied the oral Torah. We fulfill recalling "All G-d's commandments" (which are contained and alluded to  in the ten commandments) today through the recital of the paragraph on tzitzit. It's worth pointing out that this is also part of the kavanot connected to the mitzvah of tefillin too.

Comment: I was told they are out of the liturgy because of tarcha d'tzibura...

Comment: The very passage in question mentions that later rabbis sought to reinstitute it and were told not to.

Comment: @YaacovDeane -- We are not talking Oral Torah here.

Answer (score 2):

Similar  questions are frequently asked about many Gezioros which Chazal  made that the given reason  no longer seems relevant today,

The unanimous consensus is that the original Gezirah enactment remains in place for two reasons.

(1)The Rashba and other Rishonim (Forgot where) say that even when Chazal explicitly give a reason for a Gezira, the reason given is not necessarily the **only** reason. Therefore even if it no longer applies, other reasons they had may still apply.

See the Ben Ish Chai Chikrey Lev # 4 where he elaborates on this theme.

(2)The Kessef Mishneh (Hilchot Mamrim 2:2) says that both the Mishna and the Gemara were closed by a meeting of the leading rabbis of the time who finalized its contents. At those points, the contents of the Mishna and later of the Gemara were considered to be acts of a Sanhedrin that can only be changed by a later Sanhedrin of greater authority.(see also R' Tzvi Hirsch (Maharatz) Chayes in his Torat Neviim, Maamar Lo Tasur, and R' Elchanan Wasserman in his Kovetz Shiurim, Kuntres Divrei Sofrim ch. 2 for further elaboration on this point)

Sometimes there's  a question if  a specific contemporary  situation was included in the original Gezeira but a blanket Gezeira cannot be   disregarded even if the reason no longer applies

Comment: Is it so clear this is a blanket Gezera?